# How to get host cpu cores inside kubernetes pod using .net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, kubernetes-pod

I need to get host cpu cores inside kubernetes pod,but `Environment.ProcessorCount` value is pod cpu limit.How can this be done?

Just like java: [Java SE support for Docker CPU and memory limits](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/java-se-support-for-docker-cpu-and-memory-limits)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `Environment.ProcessorCount` in containers differs between versions of .NET. Also it takes processor affinity into account.

If you need to reliable get the number of host CPU cores you should use OS-specific methods. On Linux and some other operating systems, you can use the `sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF)` syscall, it is available in .NET via the NuGet packages [Mono.Posix](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix/) or [Mono.Posix.NETStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mono.Posix.NETStandard/1.0.0), or via raw PInvoke.

```
long GetTotalProcessorCount()
{
    var result = Syscall.sysconf(SysconfName._SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF);
    var error = Syscall.GetLastError();
    if (error != 0)
        // due to legacy reasons, all native exceptions in .NET are called "Win32"
        throw new Win32Exception((int)error, $"Error when calling sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF): {error} ({error:D})");
    return result;
}
```

In .NET 6 and later, you can make `Environment.ProcessorCount` return any value you want, so you can set preferred value before running the application. This is a much better way than using syscalls directly because it doesn't introduce platform-specific code into your application. It also affects internal runtime and libraries code that depend on `Environment.ProcessorCount`. To set the actual (virtual) number of host CPU cores, use:

```
export DOTNET_PROCESSOR_COUNT=$(nproc --all)
dotnet ...
```

You could learn more about it from these issues:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48094
- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/53149